# Favicon dimensions?

Tags: html, favicon

I have a favicon with the dimensions of height=26px / width=20px named favicon.png

```
<link href=http://www.example.com/images/favicon.png rel="shortcut icon" />
```

However, in my browser, my favicon.png is all distorted.

**Question**: Is my favicon.png supposed to be a particular size? Also, can I use a non-standard size/dimension and if so, how?