# set icon for my website for iphone home screen

Tags: ios, iphone, image, shortcut, favicon

I don't know if this has to do with coding but I am asking just in case: how do I set the icon to be displayed when someone creates home screen shortcut to my website on an iphone? I would have thought it would automatically do the favicon, but it isn't for mine. Maybe my favicon needs to be a greater quality (it's 32px x 32px). Thanks guys.

Comment: Did you even search at all? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Favicons - Best practice for 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029342/favicons-best-practice-for-2013)

Comment: @ Aaron: no... what's google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upload Apple touch icon files (png format) to your website and link them in the header section of your website.

For example for the retina iPhone with iOS 7+:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon120.png" sizes="120x120">
```

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046245/396578