# Best way to implement favicons for both modern desktop and mobile browsers?

Tags: favicon

Im trying to implement a favicon for a website for both mobile and desktop browsers.

AFAIK, the best way, for all desktop browsers, is currently placing a favicon.ico in the root directory of the website.

For latest version of desktop browsers, this is currently working for Chrome and Firefox. It does not work for Internet Explorer.

For mobile browsers, it does not work in Android nor in iOS.

This is what the favicon looks like in Chrome on Android:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT6sD.png

Is there a better way to do it? How can I do it for mobile browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Basically preparing a favicon could be a part of Grunt task for example like [grunt-favicons](https://github.com/gleero/grunt-favicons).

Anyway if you just need some `best practices` you could refer to the resources like [this](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/). And you could use online tools to prepare favicons with all needed markup and explanation: [realfavicongenerator.net](http://realfavicongenerator.net/)

Also refer to this question: [Favicons - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029342/favicons-best-practices)

Comment: I tried using the generator but it wont work on Android's browser nor on iOS's (Safari) browser.

Comment: Have you tried [realfavicongenerator.net](http://realfavicongenerator.net/)? Go to their website and click 'Demo with this picture' for example. There will be Android and iOS too.

Comment: Yup. Thats the one I used.

Comment: @riahc4 I'm the author of RealFaviconGenerator. We already exchanged a comment on another SO question. What you observe is definitely not normal, these cases were tested a lot of times. Is your site live so I can review it?

Comment: @philippe_b When you add to your app drawer in iOS and Android it works. The only place is does not work is on mobile browsers.

Comment: @riahc4 Sorry I don't get it. You mean that, if you add to home screen with iOS Safari or Android Chrome, you get a kind of default icon instead of the expected icon designed with RFG?

Comment: @philippe_b I added a link in the first post that shows what favicon Im talking about exactly.