# What's the recommended way to make favicon available across devices and screen resolutions in AEM 6.2?

Tags: aem, favicon

I have a use case where the favicon shows up in desktop tabs but not on mobile devices in recently viewed websites on Chrome.

Upon browsing through SO and the net, I found multiple ways like use manifest.json, browserConfig.xml or multiple  tags specifying all the expected sizes.

The documentation is pretty skewed and it is not easy to find one particular recommended way to show favicons.

These is what I have tried so far.

- Using https://realfavicongenerator.net/, I uploaded a png image for
  the favicon and included all the generated renditions, site.webmanifest and broswerconfig.xml in server root.
- After this, I included the block generated in my  tag in base template html.

Can I use this method or is there a better and more compact way to ensure favicon renders perfectly on all screen resolutions on all browsers both mobile and desktops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same best practices that hold good for a normal website hold good for an AEM application as well.

[AEM WCM Core components](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/tree/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/page/v2/page) has a working example of using multiple favicons for different viewports.

Refer to the below files from the repo.

Head.html under page component

```
<template data-sly-template.head="${ @ page }" data-sly-use.headlibRenderer="headlibs.html">
    ------------------
    <!--/* For IE 9 and below. ICO should be 32x32 pixels in size */-->
    <sly data-sly-test.faviconIco="${page.favicons['faviconIco']}">
        <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="${faviconIco}"/><![endif]-->
    </sly>
    <!--/* Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 11+ and Opera. 196x196 pixels in size. */-->
    <link data-sly-test.faviconPng="${page.favicons['faviconPng']}"
          rel="icon" type="image/png" href="${faviconPng}"/>

    <link data-sly-test="${!faviconPng && faviconIco}"
          rel="icon" href="${faviconIco}"/>

    <link data-sly-test.touchIcon60="${page.favicons['touchIcon60']}"
          rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="${touchIcon60}"/>

    <link data-sly-test.touchIcon76="${page.favicons['touchIcon76']}"
          rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="${touchIcon76}"/>

    <link data-sly-test.touchIcon120="${page.favicons['touchIcon120']}"
          rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="${touchIcon120}"/>

    <link data-sly-test.touchIcon152="${page.favicons['touchIcon152']}"
          rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="${touchIcon152}"/>

</template>
```

PageImpl.java

```
protected void loadFavicons(String designPath) {
    favicons.put(PN_FAVICON_ICO, getFaviconPath(designPath, FN_FAVICON_ICO));
    favicons.put(PN_FAVICON_PNG, getFaviconPath(designPath, FN_FAVICON_PNG));
    favicons.put(PN_TOUCH_ICON_120, getFaviconPath(designPath, FN_TOUCH_ICON_120));
    favicons.put(PN_TOUCH_ICON_152, getFaviconPath(designPath, FN_TOUCH_ICON_152));
    favicons.put(PN_TOUCH_ICON_60, getFaviconPath(designPath, FN_TOUCH_ICON_60));
    favicons.put(PN_TOUCH_ICON_76, getFaviconPath(designPath, FN_TOUCH_ICON_76));
}
```

For better understanding of favicon best practices -

- [favicon best pracs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23824196/4173416)
- [jonathan neal](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/)

Comment: This is descriptive enough. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about using realfavicongenerator to generate favicons?