# Best practice for ordering icon <link> tags in HTML head

Tags: html, icons, meta, favicon

I want to include `<link>` tags in my HTML head to various icons of different sizes. What are the best practices for ordering icon `<link>`s in the `<head>` tag? Does it matter what order I include them in? Smallest to largest? Largest to smallest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to know the information only about favicons because your question has the tag `favicon`. In other case I can write a book about it. :-) I did not find the information about the order of the sizes, but I would do it from smallest to largest order because of saving from server resources.

> **[Internet Explorer 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** uses site icons in the following places:
>
> - Address bar (`16x16`)
> - New Tab page (`32x32`)
> - Taskbar button (`32x32`)
> - Pinned site browser UI (`24x24`)
>
> As you create your Pinned site, you might need additional icons to use in the following ways:
>
> - Jump List tasks (`16x16`)
> - Thumbnail Toolbar buttons (`16x16`)
> - Overlay icons (`16x16`)
>
> To achieve the best experience in Internet Explorer 9, your icons
>   should support the following image sizes:
>
> - Recommended `16x16, 32x32, 48x48`
> - Optimal `16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 64x64`

An ICO file can contain several pictures and Microsoft recommends to put `16x16`, `32x32` and `48x48` versions of the icon in favicon.ico. For example, IE will use the `16x16` version for the address bar, and the `32x32` for a task bar shortcut.

You can write the favicon like follows:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/icons/favicon.ico">
```

Modern desktop browsers (IE11, Chrome, Opera, Firefox...) prefer to use PNG icons. The usual expected sizes are `16x16`, `32x32` and "as big as possible". For example, MacOS/Safari uses the `196x196` icon if it is the biggest it can find.

The PNG icons are declared with:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/path/to/icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/path/to/icons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
...
```

Documentation: **[<link>: The External Resource Link element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) on MDN**.

What are the recommended sizes? Pick your favorite platforms:

- **[Most desktop browsers: `16x16`, `32x32`, "as big as possible"](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility)**
- **[Android Chrome: `192x192`](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen)** (Add to Homescreen on smartphones)
- Google TV: `96x96`

The additional information about classic and not classic favicons:

- **[Favicons - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19029342)** (A lot of information a not classic favicons)
- **[Creating custom tiles for IE11 websites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn455106(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN**
- **[Here's Everything You Need to Know About Favicons in 2017](https://sympli.io/blog/2017/02/15/heres-everything-you-need-to-know-about-favicons-in-2017/)**
- **[Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)**
- **[Microsoft defines the tile picture](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/08/high-quality-visuals-for-pinned-sites-in-windows-8.aspx)**
- **[Favicon Generator](https://realfavicongenerator.net)**

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about the order of icon sizes, which is what I asked. What order should I declare the icons in?

Comment: @JulianLachniet, like I already wrote: if you want to save the server resources, then I would prefer to use from smallest to largest order. But if you want to give the users best quality icons then use from largest to smallest order.

Answer (score 3):

From the HTML5 [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/links.html#attr-link-sizes):

> The specified resource is an icon representing the page or site, and
>   should be used by the user agent when representing the page in the
>   user interface.
>
> Icons could be auditory icons, visual icons, or other kinds of icons.
>   If multiple icons are provided, the user agent must select the most
>   appropriate icon according to the type, media, and sizes attributes.
>   **If there are multiple equally appropriate icons, user agents must use
>   the last one declared in tree order at the time that the user agent
>   collected the list of icons. If the user agent tries to use an icon
>   but that icon is determined, upon closer examination, to in fact be
>   inappropriate (e.g. because it uses an unsupported format), then the
>   user agent must try the next-most-appropriate icon as determined by
>   the attributes.**

It really depends on web browser to determine which icon to use, so in my opinion ordering should not be that much of an issue. I would suggest you to follow same approach as in the example in the specs.

```
<link rel=icon href=mac.icns sizes="128x128 512x512 8192x8192 32768x32768">
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going from largest to smallest for each *rel* tag. The device or user agent should then use the highest resolution image that it can support.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mathias Bynens](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons), browsers that don't recognize the `sizes` attribute will use the last icon listed. You may want to order your icons from largest to smallest like so:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
```

That way older devices don't waste bandwidth downloading higher resolutions than they can display.

Although you didn't ask, you might want to [support Apple touchscreen devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) like the iPhone and iPad, like so:

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" sizes="180x180">
```

You must either set the `rel` attribute to `apple-touch-icon` (in which case you can name the file how you like), or put a file named `apple-touch-icon.png` in your document root, and the device will find it even without a `link` tag.

Thankfully we now live in an era where software that doesn't support the `sizes` attribute or PNG files are rare. However, SVG files are still not supported by some browsers, [notably Safari](https://caniuse.com/link-icon-svg).