# How can I show company name with logo up, when seaching in address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, web

When I search a company in URL search bar, Some companies show their logo, company name, and description which links to their website.

I really want to add this feature to my company,
so.. How can I add this feature? I even have no idea, what it is called as.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6dIC.png]

Comment: This is from the link tag in the header.  This question should give you a good answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464667/best-practice-for-ordering-icon-link-tags-in-html-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464667/best-practice-for-ordering-icon-link-tags-in-html-head)

Comment: @PiandMash Your link is just about favicon which is thumb image on the tab.

Comment: I believe the same image is shown in most browsers in their search bar if you have previously visited that site.

Comment: @PiandMash That's not what I want to know, previously visited site is just cached url,  Attached image in the question has a company description so it is not cached url and also I can not delete it from search result. If you hover over result urls, in case of visited sites 'X' icon(delete icon) appears on the right side

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't help. Hopefully someone else will post your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a google business profile. https://business.google.com/create

It will take the added photo of the profile and display it automatically. Don't know if it's instant to be honest (can be google needs to index it first), but in the end it will work. Have double checked it for you with a company I maintain. And they have the same icon in search bar like you requested. ✌️