# Favicon is pixelated in windows taskbar

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon, taskbar

I have to set favicon for my website but icon always looks very bad in windows taskbar although I use icon 130x130

My html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

How it looks:

[image: example]

Amazon icon was taken just as example.

Icon was created by icon plugin for Paint.NET. Also i tried to create icon with 128x128 and 64x64, result was worse. Also i tried to use 256x256 result is better, but still is pixelated. But if i create link on this page on task bar icon will be fine.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You might want to look around a bit, to posts like these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268204/favicon-dimensions. Also, 130x130 is not a standard icon size, meaning there will be no situation in which the icon can be used. It will always have to be resized by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single link like this isn't enough, browsers won't just automatically resize and use the favicon appropriately. Try following this nice [favicon cheat sheet](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet).

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft recommends to put three pictures in the `favicon.ico` file: 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). IE is able to pick the suitable one. Chrome and Firefox use a PNG icon, declared with:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

This [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) produces such `favicon.ico` and PNG icons. The end result is fine. [When adding an icon to the task bar, IE uses the 32x32 picture, Chrome the 196x196 PNG picture and Firefox the 32x32 PNG picture](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility). Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

Comment: Thank for you reply, great site. But chrome still shows pixelated icon, so i guess problem not in favicon.ico. I guess problem in Chrome.

Comment: Oops! You are totally right :( I edited the answer to take Chrome and FF into account.

Answer (score 0):

Standard icon size is 16X16 px. or 32X32 px. so use this size. 
favicon (due CSS3) needn't be in .ico file. Just try to use .png file

Answer (score -1):

Use favicon as .svg (vector) file instead of .png it will definitely work and not pixealated.