# How to add an icon to tabs for HTML/Jquery Tabs for use in Episys Symitar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

New programmer here. I mostly program in Symitar PowerOn but recently found through a marketplace a way to organize our Specfile in a tabbed format. I got all the coding done and now would like to add my Credit Unions logo on the tabs. Also help with getting a background picture that would show up globally would be most appreciated. Apologies for the bad formatting, I am very new. Any help/opions would be most appreciated.

```
PROCEDURE SHOWUSERMAINMENU 
        HTMLVIEWOPEN 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("<!DOCTYPE HTML>") 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("<html>") 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("<head>") 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("<meta http-equiv="+Q+"X-UA-Compatible"+Q+" content="+Q+"IE=9"+Q+" />") 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("<title>Main Menu</title>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("<script type="+Q+"text/javascript"+Q+" src="+Q+"G:\All\symform\forms\Tab Layout\jquery.js"+Q+"></script>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("<script type="+Q+"text/javascript"+Q+" src="+Q+"G:\All\symform\forms\Tab Layout\jquery-ui.min.js"+Q+"></script>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("<link type="+Q+"text/css"+Q+" href="+Q+"G:\All\symform\forms\Tab Layout\jquery-ui.structure.min.css"+Q+" rel="+Q+"stylesheet"+Q+" />") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("<link type="+Q+"text/css"+Q+" href="+Q+"G:\All\symform\forms\Tab Layout\jquery-ui.theme.min.css"+Q+" rel="+Q+"stylesheet"+Q+" />") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("<script type='text/javascript'>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("function sbmtRgName(rgName){") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" var h = document.createElement('input');") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" h.type = 'hidden';") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" h.id = 'rgName';") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" h.name = 'rgName';") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" h.value = rgName;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" document.form1.appendChild(h);") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" document.form1.submit();") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("}") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("$(document).ready(function(){") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("   $('#tabs').tabs();") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("   $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({ ") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("               source: ") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("[") 
    FOR X=1 TO CAT 
    DO 
        FOR Y=1 TO VALUE(RGNAMES(X, 0, 0)) 
        DO 
            IF RGNAMES(X, Y, 1)<>"" THEN 
            DO 
                HTMLVIEWLINE("{"+Q+"value"+Q+":"+Q+RGNAMES(X, Y, 1)+Q+","+Q+"id"+Q+":"+Q+rgnames(X, Y, 0)+Q+"},") 
            END 

        END 

    END 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("]") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("}); ") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("   $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("               select: function(event, ui) {sbmtRgName(ui.item.id); }") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("});") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("});") [doc.ready] 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("</script>") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("<style type='text/css'>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("body{") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" font: 10px "+Q+"Tahoma"+Q+", sans-serif;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" margin: 5px;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("}") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE(".rgListClass{") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" list-style-type:none;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" margin:0px;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" padding:0px;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("}") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE(".rgListClass li a{") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" text-decoration:none;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" font-weight:normal;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" font-size:15px;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("}") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE(".rgListClass li{") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" padding-bottom:3px;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("}") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE(".searchClass{") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" z-index: 100;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" position: absolute;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" right:2px;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("}") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE(".menuClass{") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" position:relative;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" width:100%;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("}") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE(".menuColumn{") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" float:left;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE(" padding-left:5px;") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("}") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("</style>") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("</head>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("<body onLoad="+Q+"javascript:document.getElementById('autocomplete').focus();"+Q+">") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("<form name='form1' id='form1' method='post' action='symitar://HTMLView~Action=Post'>") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("<div id='tabs'>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("<ul>") 
    FOR X=1 TO CAT 
    DO 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("<li style='font-weight:bold;'><a href='#cat-"+FORMAT("99", X)+"'>") 
        HTMLVIEWLINE(CATEGORY(X, 0)) 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("</a></li>") 
    END 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("</ul>") 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("<div class='searchClass'>Search:") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("<input id='autocomplete' title='Start typing a menu function' /> ") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("</div>") 

    FOR X=1 TO CAT 
    DO 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("<div id='cat-"+FORMAT("99", X)+"' class='menuClass'>") 
        FOR Y=1 TO VALUE(RGNAMES(X, 0, 0)) 
        DO 
            IF RGNAMES(X, Y, 1)="" THEN 
            DO 
                IF Y=1 THEN 
                HTMLVIEWLINE("<div class='menuColumn'>") 
                ELSE 
                DO 
                    HTMLVIEWLINE("</ul>") 
                    HTMLVIEWLINE("</div>") 
                    HTMLVIEWLINE("<div class='menuColumn' style='margin-left:50px;'>") 
                END 

                HTMLVIEWLINE("<h2>"+RGNAMES(X, Y, 0)+"</h2>") 
                HTMLVIEWLINE("<ul class='rgListClass'>") 
            END 

            HTMLVIEWLINE("<li>") 
            IF RGNAMES(X, Y, 1)<>"" THEN 
            DO 
                HTMLVIEWLINE("<a href="+Q+"javascript:sbmtRgName('"+RGNAMES(X, Y, 0)+"');"+Q+">") 
                HTMLVIEWLINE(RGNAMES(X, Y, 1)+"</a>") 
            END 

            HTMLVIEWLINE("</li>") 
        END 

        HTMLVIEWLINE("</ul>") 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("</div>") 
        HTMLVIEWLINE("</div>") 
    END 

    HTMLVIEWLINE("<div style='clear:both;height:10px'></div>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("</div>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("</form>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("</body>") 
    HTMLVIEWLINE("</html>") 
    HTMLVIEWDISPLAY 
    SUBNAME="" 
    TMP=ENTERLINE(0) 
    WHILE TMP<>"EOD" 
    DO 
        IF SEGMENT(TMP, 1, 7)="rgName=" THEN 
        SUBNAME=SEGMENT(TMP, 8, LENGTH(TMP)) 
        TMP=ENTERLINE(0) 
    END 

    IF SUBNAME<>"" THEN 
    DO 
        INITSUBROUTINE(SUBERR) 
        EXECUTE(SUBNAME, SUBERR) 
    END 

END
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Symitar PowerOn but, to have your logo on the tabs like in this picture http://screencast.com/t/iAXFTnIBbA your logo has to be 16x16 pixels, *.ico format, and for your second question I'm not familiar enough with Symitar to know how to do it but googling it may help :)

Source: [Favicon dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268204/favicon-dimensions)