# Create shortcut icon for locally stored web app for Firefox Android

Tags: android, firefox, favicon

I have created a local web app for Android that I want to use with Firefox. My problem is that I'm not able to get the desktop shortcut to have the app icon, and even on the tabs in FF, a white S on a green background is displayed (it's the same icon used for the shortcut).

Chrome is able to display the icon but due to various reasons (http vs https restrictions, inability to access external SD card storage, inability to create desktop shortcut for local web apps...) I have to use Firefox.

I have used the content generated with https://realfavicongenerator.net to no avail. Websites, though, do display their icons both in tabs and when a shortcut is created on the desktop, so FF is not broken on the device.

I have read through some of the questions here on SO ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268204/favicon-dimensions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301745/how-to-set-up-a-favicon)) as well as the FAQ on realfavicongenerator.net but nothing points specifically to locally stored web apps and FF.

Comment: RFG'author speaking. When running the compatibility test (https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility_test), FF is using the 180x180 Touch icon (https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility). But you don't observe this, is that correct?

Comment: @philippe_b Actually FF is using the 180x180 Apple Touch icon.

Comment: Well this is apparently how FF behaves. Like many browsers, it is using the Touch icon as a good high resolution icon (which it is). Do you consider this as a big issue? Or did you just wish Chrome and FF to behave the same way, because they both run on Android?

Comment: @philippe_b Whether FF and Chrome behave in a similar way or not is not my issue here. My problem is that I can't get FF to display the icon, nor have it show the icon for the desktop shortcut. I have used the default output from RFG as well as trying to alter it to keep only the Touch icon but without any success. Reminder that the page is locally stored on the device (if that makes any difference), and I only want to use FF.

Comment: If you don't access the site/webapp via HTTP but via file:// URL, yes, that can make a difference. Although I have little knowledge regarding this case, I already observed difference in behavior when using a local site. Possible ways to go on with this issue: 1) Change the touch icon name (both file and HTML markup) to force FF to reload. 2) Try with another device (to avoid caching issues; you'll never be too careful about this). 3) Serve your app with a local HTTP server... super-heavy if this is just a way to fix this issue!

Comment: Thanks @philippe_b. Will go with suggestions 1 and 2. As you say, 3 is not a practical option just for a shortcut icon as the app is working well otherwise. If anything comes up, I will update this post.